# Why in some case, a tag can't be append again

Tags: support, tags, revisions-list, edits

When someone remove a tag on a user question, then the user who created the question can't append it again, even it the was removed with no real reasons...

Are there any exceptions to this? If not, I think some should be added.

Comment: That can happen if the tag has become a synonym since it was originally added.

Comment: I was thinking to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209786/242800), were the `HTML` tag was removed. Since the removal, I can't add it again. If I make an edit, consisting only of adding the `HTML` tag, it don't appear in the revision list history even when I remove the `design` tag.

Comment: The [meta-tag:html] tag was synonymized into [meta-tag:design]... So trying to add it will rewrite the tag to [meta-tag:design], which already exists on the question.

Comment: I ran into that specific case on the first question I asked on Meta actually.

Comment: @animuson : Even if I REMOVE the TAG I CAN'T add IT!

Comment: @user2284570 You never added it to begin with... It's not *possible* to add that tag, and hasn't been since August 16th when the synonym was created.

Comment: If you remove `[design]` and then try adding `[html]` without saving in between these steps, the system will rewrite `[html]` back into `[design]` before the save, resulting in an effective no-op and therefore no edit to put into the edit history. If you save between the two steps, you will get rid of `[design]` and then re-add it.  that's still an effective no-op when the edits are combined by the edit history.

Comment: You should post an answer, @animuson. Explain what a synonym is, why it's similar but not at all the same as a tag merge, and why this is confusing when one happens without the other. It'll save time in the long run...

Comment: @Charles : This what I'm expecting, but this doesn't WORK! I REALLY CAN'T add the `html`tag AGAIN!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [html](/questions/tagged/html) tag was made a synonym to [design](/questions/tagged/design) on August 16th, because it was primarily used to discuss the HTML structure of Stack Exchange sites, which is a design issue. However, a synonym only redirects *new* uses of the tag to the master tag. Old occurrences keep the tag, which can cause some confusion. In order to fix that, the tags would need to be merged. I could have done that when creating the synonym, but I wanted to leave it alone in case users thought the synonym should be undone (once it's merged, there's no going back).

If you start a new question and type "html" into the tags box, you're going to see a popup similar to this:

[image: HTML tag popup]

A very convenient [html](/questions/tagged/html) tag pops up in second place. However, notice the "**also:html**" below the [design](/questions/tagged/design) tag. That appears there because it is currently a synonym to that tag. So, from seeing this, one can assume that [html](/questions/tagged/html) is a synonym to [design](/questions/tagged/design) and that there are currently still 137 questions that had the [html](/questions/tagged/html) tag when the synonym was created.

If you proceed to try and use the [html](/questions/tagged/html) tag, your box will appear as this:

[image: HTML tag enetered]

Looks like you can use the tag, but you can't. When a post (or edit) gets submitted, it goes through some server-side checks:

1. It checks to make sure you are not using any blacklisted tags, and forbids you from submitting if so.
2. It checks to make sure the tag exists. If it does not, and you do not have the privilege to create tags, it forbids you from submitting.
3. It checks to see if that tag is a synonym of another tag, and if so, **rewrites that tag to the master tag**. Essentially, the tag changes to whatever the master tag is and the synonym is removed.
4. It checks to make sure there are no duplicate tags and removes any of them.

So if you were to submit the post with that tag, the [html](/questions/tagged/html) tag gets *changed* into a [design](/questions/tagged/design) tag. So if the [design](/questions/tagged/design) tag already exists on your question, it will appear as if nothing happened. When actually writing the question, it will appear as if the system added a tag that you did not enter.

---

In your specific case: the [html](/questions/tagged/html) tag was *never on the question*. From the get-go when you submitted the question, it got changed to [design](/questions/tagged/design) immediately upon posting, since that synonym has existed for a long time before you posted your question.

Comment: I said `removed` not replaced! If I make a two-step edit, it don't WORK! I can remove the `design` tag. But If I add HTML after the removal, it don't append the `HTML` tag, but the `design` one.

Comment: And that is by design. Read the answer again.

Comment: @user2284570 You can't remove a tag that was never on the question to begin with, though. I don't think you're grasping the fact that it really never was on the question.

Comment: @user2284570 Let's try it like this, for the sake of having you understand: Add the [html] tag to this question of yours and see what happens.

Comment: @Bart : Ok, So, The HTML tag is useless and not used anymore, why is it not removed?

Comment: It is not removed, it has been synonymized. It is now actively replaced by the [design] tag whenever you try to use it.

Comment: See also: [What are tag synonyms? How do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)

Comment: @Bart : Are you meaning this question is a duplicate?